# Bash: find string in file and delete the next line

Tags: bash, replace

I try to find a line in a text file and delete the next line.

I've tested the following code (and some variations) but I'm stuck at the sed command not taking the $ from the stdin therefore not making what I need.

```
cat test.txt | grep -in mystring | awk -F: '{print $1+1}' | sed -i "$,1d" test.txt
```

Comment: not sure what yoru above code is doing, but `sed '/mystring/{p;N;d}' file` or  `sed '/mystring/{n;d}' file` will delete the next line of `mystring`

Comment: Yup, your code does exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sed -i '/^yourstring/{n;d}' filename.txt
```

Comment: Your answer is obsolete.

Comment: This code, as the PS's above, does exactly what I need. Thank you.